# Implementing popUp menu with appcompat 7 library

Tags: android, android-appcompat

So my popup Menu works fine on 4.0 phones but throws this exception on lower versions. 
I've been trying to figure out something for hours now, with no solution.

Here's the Menu XML, I'm not sure if I'm supposed to be looking at another layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        >
  <group android:id="@+id/group_popupmenu">
     <item android:id="@+id/menu1"
         android:title="@string/remove_recipient"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/menu2"
       android:title="@string/assign_resp"/>
  </group>

</menu>
```

Here is where it's set:

```
public void showPopupMenu(final RecipientChip chip) {

    PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(_cont, this);
    popupMenu.getMenuInflater().inflate(
            R.menu.resp_popupmenu, popupMenu.getMenu());

    if (!_responsibilityEnabled)
        hideOption(R.id.menu2, popupMenu.getMenu());

                      ...
```

I'm really not sure what I'm doing wrong. I seem to have looked through the XML files for a cause:

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #17: You must supply a layout_height attribute.
at android.content.res.TypedArray.getLayoutDimension(TypedArray.java:491)
at android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams.setBaseAttributes(ViewGroup.java:3599)
at android.view.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams.<init>(ViewGroup.java:3678)
at android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams.<init>(FrameLayout.java:457)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.generateLayoutParams(FrameLayout.java:423)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.generateLayoutParams(FrameLayout.java:47)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper$MenuAdapter.getView(MenuPopupHelper.java:335)
at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.measureContentWidth(MenuPopupHelper.java:190)
at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.tryShow(MenuPopupHelper.java:128)
at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.show(MenuPopupHelper.java:102)
at android.support.v7.widget.PopupMenu.show(PopupMenu.java:108)
at com.path.ChipTextView.showPopupMenu(ChipTextView.java:420)
at com.path.RecipientChip$1.onClick(RecipientChip.java:233)
at com.path.ChipTextView$MyMovementMethod.onTouchEvent(ChipTextView.java:610)
at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:6863)
at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3885)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:942)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:942)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:942)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:942)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:942)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:942)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:942)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:942)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:942)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:942)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:942)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:942)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:942)
    at   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1691)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1125)
at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2096)
at com.path.FragmentActivity.dispatchTouchEvent(FragmentActivity.java:97)
at   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1675)
at android.view.ViewRoot.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRoot.java:2194)
at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1878)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android V7 Support Library Popup Menu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17975002/android-v7-support-library-popup-menu) - as you can read on the dup, `PopupMenu(this,v)` needs to refer to (1.)the Context and (2.)the View. What is `_cont` and `chip` in the method? Because I think it might be `PopupMenu(this,chip)` instead (with the hope that `chip` is a view).

Comment: It is the activity context and view respectively though. As I said, it works on 4.0 devices.

Comment: I'm not sure about where the height attribute goes in all of this, but I also have the Appcompat theme.

Comment: Do you have the right import: `android.support.v7.widget.PopupMenu`?

Comment: Yes I checked, I do. I'm not sure if I need a different XML file though. The current one is located in the menu folder.

Comment: The issue might be caused by the custom view `Recipient`. Try using `View v` instead. Here is a [simple tutorial](http://danielme.com/2014/03/08/diseno-android-popup-menu/) (in Spanish but nevermind), you can clearly see how it works.

Comment: Check the solution in this link [Link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22820204/runtimeexception-binary-xml-file-line-17-you-must-supply-a-layout-height-attr/32274104#32274104