# error popup menu in appcompat v7 Binary XML file line #17: You must supply a layout_height attribute

Tags: android, popup, popupmenu

I open PopupMenu as follows:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v.getId() == R.id.action_reading) {
        PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(context, v);
        popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem arg0) {
                System.out.println("------ click menu");
                return false;
            }
        });
        popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.action_reading_menu, popup.getMenu());
        popup.show();
    }
}
```

In the `action_reading` xml:

```
<Button android:id="@+id/action_reading"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
```

In the `action_reading_menu` xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:id="@+id/delete_item_reading"
        android:title="Delete"
        android:visible="true"></item>
</menu>
```

I was set height for `action_reading` then but still get the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #17: You must supply a layout_height attribute.
```

Anyone know why I got this error message and solve it like?

UPDATE all xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="2dp"
    android:paddingLeft="4dp"
    android:paddingRight="4dp"
    android:paddingTop="2dp" >

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cv_benefit"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="110dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title_story_list_menu"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/action_reading"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/cover_image_reading"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:text="title story"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/cover_image_reading"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:src="@drawable/img_bg" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/title_story_list_menu"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/cover_image_reading"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_account_circle_grey_36dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/author_list"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/title_story_list_menu"
                android:layout_below="@+id/title_story_list_menu"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView3"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:text="ss"
                android:textColor="@color/grey700" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/parts"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:text="78"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/cover_image_reading"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_visibility_grey_36dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/readed"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView2"
                android:text="123456789"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/parts"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_book_grey_36dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/action_reading"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_more_vert_grey600_18dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Try to set height="wrap content"

Comment: I still get that error

Comment: Could you please post the full xml or at least the lines before the button.

Comment: Hmm line 17 doesn't seem to be the Button? Have you tried to rebuild your R file?

Comment: yes i have clean and rebuild project. but still that error

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22820204/runtimeexception-binary-xml-file-line-17-you-must-supply-a-layout-height-attr